# Recovering MySQL database from live server MySQL data to local server MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp, database-restore

I have a live project and I am using phpMyAdmin and Ubuntu Server 16.04. I have lost my phpMyAdmin login access, but using FTP access I downloaded my database suppose name productions folder from MySQL data folder. Now, I want to import this  productions database to my local server (using XAMPP).

I was trying to copy this folder and moved it to my local MySQL/data folder. The database is showing the table name but doesn't show any result, and when I click any table it's showing an error. How can I restore this database into my local server? Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have console access to the server you can use `mysqldump -u*username* -p*password* databasename > somefile.sql`
Then import that sql file into your local database